# Windows Login Names and their impact on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Does anyone know of the impact on SQL Server of adopting 'two part' user Windows Loginnames in the form "fred.bloggs" instead of "bloggsf"?

I have scoured the Microsoft Knowledgebase and can nothing clear about one or the other: only that all examples shown by them are in the 'single word' format.

I have tried to use fred.bloggs ( that is fred dot bloggs ) in some SQL statements and get error messages, so they obviously cannot be used in a straight forward form.

Answer (score 0):

There is no impact on the SQL Server engine and performance.

A user name is a user name, whether there is a `.` in the middle or not.

The only issue is that of how the name is interpreted - ensure you use `[]` when specifying a user name, otherwise SQL will interpret the part before the `.` as a schema name.

So, for `CREATE LOGIN`, you should do:

```
CREATE LOGIN [xxxxx.yyyyy]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap a login like this in brackets, like: `[your.login]`